# The Usage of "ask"

Tags: verbs, objects

Are the sentences below correct?

1. > I asked "Please send me some money."

   Can you use *ask* in direct discourse?
2. > John: What did you ask Tom?
   >   Megan: I asked "leave me alone."

   Can you omit the object *him*?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I do not think I would use ***ask*** in 'direct discourse' in either of the examples you quote.

In those instances *ask* is being used as a request, not strictly as a question. Were it a question I would not hesitate to use it directly. For example:

> 'Where did you go on Sunday?', she **asked**
>    Or
>   They will justifiably **ask** 'What do you intend to do about the matter?'

But whilst it is perfectly grammatical to use **ask** to mean ***request***, it seems very awkward if employed for direct speech. But it would certainly be alright to say

> I **asked him** to please send some money.

I have no doubt that the true grammarians on the site will explain this far more succinctly than I can.